# Getting Entries that were updated after a certain day?

Tags: plugin-development

I need to get all the entries that were updated after a certain date, I tried a couple things, but it doesn't seem to work, does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

This seems wrong to me, but it doesn't throw any error, neither does it accomplish what I want.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'affiliates';
$criteria->dateUpdated("> '2015-09-02'");

$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
$queryResults = $query->queryAll();

$affiliates = EntryModel::populateModels($queryResults);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your criteria for the date updated was written in the wrong syntax. It should be:

`$criteria->dateUpdated = '> 2015-09-02';`

You can also simplify the way you query your Element Criteria Model like so:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'affiliates';
$criteria->dateUpdated = '> 2015-09-02';
$affiliates = $criteria->find();
```

Take a look at the [Working with Elements](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) documentation for more info.